# Windows Media Player - Always on top

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

How to make WMP to always stay on top when playing? I remember it had that option in View Menu in old WMP, but in WMP11 it's not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into :
Organise -> Options
Click the Player Tab
Select the Tick Box - Keep Now Playing On Top Of Other Windows

Answer (score 0):

In version 12 you can find it

//If you can't finds tools click on your player then `Alt` From your keyboard to show this up

Tools --> Options

Player --> check  `Keep Now Playing On Top Of Other Windows`